# reduction in array index and update the array using openmp in Fortran

Tags: fortran, openmp

Basically what im trying to do is to collect the array of `flg` where its coordinate (`rlon_mband`, `rlat_mband`) within certain radius (`radii`) and save it as a new array `inflg`.

As you can notice from the one thread result the order of the index in the new array 'inflg' is monotonically increasing (`im=1,2,3...`), while if I used multiple threads the order of the array index just changes randomly.

I think its something with initializing the `im1` within each thread. But if you put `im1` as `shared` or `reduction` then the order of the index for the new array `inflg` will be a mess...

```
program test
implicit none
integer,parameter :: iscan=50,ifov=20
real,   parameter :: radii=6.0
integer :: im1, m,n
real :: temp,rLonMax,rLonmin,rLatMin,rLatMax
real :: rLon_Mband(ifov, iscan),rLat_Mband(ifov, iscan)
real :: flg(ifov, iscan)
real :: inflg(1000)


do m=1,iscan
do n=1,ifov
    rLon_Mband(n,m)=0.5+0.01*m+0.1*n
enddo
enddo

do m=1,iscan
do n=1,ifov
    rLat_Mband(n,m)=-10.0+0.1*m+0.01*n
enddo
enddo

print*,'rLon_Mband=', rLon_Mband(1:10,1),maxval(rLon_Mband(:,1))
print*,'rLat_Mband', rLat_Mband(1:10,1),maxval(rLat_mband(1,:))

do m=1,iscan
do n=1,ifov
    flg(n,m)=100*sin(real(m/iscan))+100*cos(real(n/ifov))
enddo
enddo

rLonMax=10.0
rLonmin=0.001
rLatMin=-10.0
rLatMax=10.0


iM1=1; temp=9999.0
!$omp parallel do default(none) &
!$omp private(m,n,temp,im1)&
!$omp shared(rLonMax,rLonmin,rLatMax,rLatmin)&
!$omp shared(flg,inflg,rlon_mband,rlat_mband)
do m=1,iScan
do n=1,iFov
!print*,'lon=', rLon_Mband(n,m)
!print*,'lat=', rLat_Mband(n,m)
  if ((rLon_Mband(n,m)<=rLonMax) .and.  &
     (rLon_Mband(n,m)>=rLonMin) .and. &
     (rLat_Mband(n,m)<=rLatMax).and.  &
     (rLat_Mband(n,m)>=rLatMin)) then
     temp=sqrt(rLon_Mband(n,m)**2+rLat_mband(n,m)**2)
     !print*,'temp', temp
     if (temp<=radii) then  ! 
        inflg(iM1)    = flg(n,m)
        print*,'im1,t=',iM1,flg(n,m), n,m
        iM1 = iM1+1
     end if
  end if
end do
end do  ! end_do
!$omp end parallel do


end program test
```

When I used only one thread I got results like this:

```
rLon_Mband=  0.610000014      0.709999979      0.810000002      0.909999967       1.00999999       1.11000001       1.21000004       1.30999994       1.41000009       1.50999999       2.50999999    
 rLat_Mband  -9.88999939      -9.87999916      -9.86999989      -9.85999966      -9.84999943      -9.83999920      -9.82999992      -9.81999969      -9.80999947      -9.79999924      -4.98999977    
 im1,t=           0   100.000000               1          41
 im1,t=           1   100.000000               2          41
 im1,t=           2   100.000000               3          41
 im1,t=           3   100.000000               1          42
 im1,t=           4   100.000000               2          42
 im1,t=           5   100.000000               3          42
 im1,t=           6   100.000000               4          42
 im1,t=           7   100.000000               5          42
 im1,t=           8   100.000000               6          42
 im1,t=           9   100.000000               7          42
 im1,t=          10   100.000000               8          42
 im1,t=          11   100.000000               9          42
 im1,t=          12   100.000000               1          43
 im1,t=          13   100.000000               2          43
 im1,t=          14   100.000000               3          43
 im1,t=          15   100.000000               4          43
 im1,t=          16   100.000000               5          43
 im1,t=          17   100.000000               6          43
 im1,t=          18   100.000000               7          43
 im1,t=          19   100.000000               8          43
 im1,t=          20   100.000000               9          43
 im1,t=          21   100.000000              10          43
 im1,t=          22   100.000000              11          43
 im1,t=          23   100.000000              12          43
 im1,t=          24   100.000000              13          43
 im1,t=          25   100.000000               1          44
 im1,t=          26   100.000000               2          44
 im1,t=          27   100.000000               3          44
 im1,t=          28   100.000000               4          44
 im1,t=          29   100.000000               5          44
 im1,t=          30   100.000000               6          44
 im1,t=          31   100.000000               7          44
 im1,t=          32   100.000000               8          44
 im1,t=          33   100.000000               9          44
 im1,t=          34   100.000000              10          44
 im1,t=          35   100.000000              11          44
 im1,t=          36   100.000000              12          44
 im1,t=          37   100.000000              13          44
 im1,t=          38   100.000000              14          44
 im1,t=          39   100.000000              15          44
 im1,t=          40   100.000000               1          45
 im1,t=          41   100.000000               2          45
 im1,t=          42   100.000000               3          45
 im1,t=          43   100.000000               4          45
 im1,t=          44   100.000000               5          45
 im1,t=          45   100.000000               6          45
 im1,t=          46   100.000000               7          45
 im1,t=          47   100.000000               8          45
 im1,t=          48   100.000000               9          45
 im1,t=          49   100.000000              10          45
 im1,t=          50   100.000000              11          45
 im1,t=          51   100.000000              12          45
 im1,t=          52   100.000000              13          45
 im1,t=          53   100.000000              14          45
 im1,t=          54   100.000000              15          45
 im1,t=          55   100.000000              16          45
 im1,t=          56   100.000000              17          45
 im1,t=          57   100.000000              18          45
 im1,t=          58   100.000000               1          46
 im1,t=          59   100.000000               2          46
 im1,t=          60   100.000000               3          46
 im1,t=          61   100.000000               4          46
 im1,t=          62   100.000000               5          46
 im1,t=          63   100.000000               6          46
 im1,t=          64   100.000000               7          46
 im1,t=          65   100.000000               8          46
 im1,t=          66   100.000000               9          46
 im1,t=          67   100.000000              10          46
 im1,t=          68   100.000000              11          46
 im1,t=          69   100.000000              12          46
 im1,t=          70   100.000000              13          46
 im1,t=          71   100.000000              14          46
 im1,t=          72   100.000000              15          46
 im1,t=          73   100.000000              16          46
 im1,t=          74   100.000000              17          46
 im1,t=          75   100.000000              18          46
 im1,t=          76   100.000000              19          46
 im1,t=          77   54.0302277              20          46
 im1,t=          78   100.000000               1          47
 im1,t=          79   100.000000               2          47
 im1,t=          80   100.000000               3          47
 im1,t=          81   100.000000               4          47
 im1,t=          82   100.000000               5          47
 im1,t=          83   100.000000               6          47
 im1,t=          84   100.000000               7          47
 im1,t=          85   100.000000               8          47
 im1,t=          86   100.000000               9          47
 im1,t=          87   100.000000              10          47
 im1,t=          88   100.000000              11          47
 im1,t=          89   100.000000              12          47
 im1,t=          90   100.000000              13          47
 im1,t=          91   100.000000              14          47
 im1,t=          92   100.000000              15          47
 im1,t=          93   100.000000              16          47
 im1,t=          94   100.000000              17          47
 im1,t=          95   100.000000              18          47
 im1,t=          96   100.000000              19          47
 im1,t=          97   54.0302277              20          47
 im1,t=          98   100.000000               1          48
 im1,t=          99   100.000000               2          48
 im1,t=         100   100.000000               3          48
 im1,t=         101   100.000000               4          48
 im1,t=         102   100.000000               5          48
 im1,t=         103   100.000000               6          48
 im1,t=         104   100.000000               7          48
 im1,t=         105   100.000000               8          48
 im1,t=         106   100.000000               9          48
 im1,t=         107   100.000000              10          48
 im1,t=         108   100.000000              11          48
 im1,t=         109   100.000000              12          48
 im1,t=         110   100.000000              13          48
 im1,t=         111   100.000000              14          48
 im1,t=         112   100.000000              15          48
 im1,t=         113   100.000000              16          48
 im1,t=         114   100.000000              17          48
 im1,t=         115   100.000000              18          48
 im1,t=         116   100.000000              19          48
 im1,t=         117   54.0302277              20          48
 im1,t=         118   100.000000               1          49
 im1,t=         119   100.000000               2          49
 im1,t=         120   100.000000               3          49
 im1,t=         121   100.000000               4          49
 im1,t=         122   100.000000               5          49
 im1,t=         123   100.000000               6          49
 im1,t=         124   100.000000               7          49
 im1,t=         125   100.000000               8          49
 im1,t=         126   100.000000               9          49
 im1,t=         127   100.000000              10          49
 im1,t=         128   100.000000              11          49
 im1,t=         129   100.000000              12          49
 im1,t=         130   100.000000              13          49
 im1,t=         131   100.000000              14          49
 im1,t=         132   100.000000              15          49
 im1,t=         133   100.000000              16          49
 im1,t=         134   100.000000              17          49
 im1,t=         135   100.000000              18          49
 im1,t=         136   100.000000              19          49
 im1,t=         137   54.0302277              20          49
 im1,t=         138   184.147095               1          50
 im1,t=         139   184.147095               2          50
 im1,t=         140   184.147095               3          50
 im1,t=         141   184.147095               4          50
 im1,t=         142   184.147095               5          50
 im1,t=         143   184.147095               6          50
 im1,t=         144   184.147095               7          50
 im1,t=         145   184.147095               8          50
 im1,t=         146   184.147095               9          50
 im1,t=         147   184.147095              10          50
 im1,t=         148   184.147095              11          50
 im1,t=         149   184.147095              12          50
 im1,t=         150   184.147095              13          50
 im1,t=         151   184.147095              14          50
 im1,t=         152   184.147095              15          50
 im1,t=         153   184.147095              16          50
 im1,t=         154   184.147095              17          50
 im1,t=         155   184.147095              18          50
 im1,t=         156   184.147095              19          50
 im1,t=         157   138.177322              20          50
```

However when I executed the program and

```
 export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2
```

I got this output:

```
rLon_Mband=  0.610000014      0.709999979      0.810000002      0.909999967       1.00999999       1.11000001       1.21000004       1.30999994       1.41000009       1.50999999       2.50999999    
 rLat_Mband  -9.88999939      -9.87999916      -9.86999989      -9.85999966      -9.84999943      -9.83999920      -9.82999992      -9.81999969      -9.80999947      -9.79999924      -4.98999977    
 im1,t=         512   100.000000               1          41
 im1,t=         513   100.000000               2          41
 im1,t=         514   100.000000               3          41
 im1,t=         515   100.000000               1          42
 im1,t=         516   100.000000               2          42
 im1,t=         517   100.000000               3          42
 im1,t=         518   100.000000               4          42
 im1,t=         519   100.000000               5          42
 im1,t=         520   100.000000               6          42
 im1,t=         521   100.000000               7          42
 im1,t=         522   100.000000               8          42
 im1,t=         523   100.000000               9          42
 im1,t=         524   100.000000               1          43
 im1,t=         525   100.000000               2          43
 im1,t=         526   100.000000               3          43
 im1,t=         527   100.000000               4          43
 im1,t=         528   100.000000               5          43
 im1,t=         529   100.000000               6          43
 im1,t=         530   100.000000               7          43
 im1,t=         531   100.000000               8          43
 im1,t=         532   100.000000               9          43
 im1,t=         533   100.000000              10          43
 im1,t=         534   100.000000              11          43
 im1,t=         535   100.000000              12          43
 im1,t=         536   100.000000              13          43
 im1,t=         537   100.000000               1          44
 im1,t=         538   100.000000               2          44
 im1,t=         539   100.000000               3          44
 im1,t=         540   100.000000               4          44
 im1,t=         541   100.000000               5          44
 im1,t=         542   100.000000               6          44
 im1,t=         543   100.000000               7          44
 im1,t=         544   100.000000               8          44
 im1,t=         545   100.000000               9          44
 im1,t=         546   100.000000              10          44
 im1,t=         547   100.000000              11          44
 im1,t=         548   100.000000              12          44
 im1,t=         549   100.000000              13          44
 im1,t=         550   100.000000              14          44
 im1,t=         551   100.000000              15          44
 im1,t=         552   100.000000               1          45
 im1,t=         553   100.000000               2          45
 im1,t=         554   100.000000               3          45
 im1,t=         555   100.000000               4          45
 im1,t=         556   100.000000               5          45
 im1,t=         557   100.000000               6          45
 im1,t=         558   100.000000               7          45
 im1,t=         559   100.000000               8          45
 im1,t=         560   100.000000               9          45
 im1,t=         561   100.000000              10          45
 im1,t=         562   100.000000              11          45
 im1,t=         563   100.000000              12          45
 im1,t=         564   100.000000              13          45
 im1,t=         565   100.000000              14          45
 im1,t=         566   100.000000              15          45
 im1,t=         567   100.000000              16          45
 im1,t=         568   100.000000              17          45
 im1,t=         569   100.000000              18          45
 im1,t=         570   100.000000               1          46
 im1,t=         571   100.000000               2          46
 im1,t=         572   100.000000               3          46
 im1,t=         573   100.000000               4          46
 im1,t=         574   100.000000               5          46
 im1,t=         575   100.000000               6          46
 im1,t=         576   100.000000               7          46
 im1,t=         577   100.000000               8          46
 im1,t=         578   100.000000               9          46
 im1,t=         579   100.000000              10          46
 im1,t=         580   100.000000              11          46
 im1,t=         581   100.000000              12          46
 im1,t=         582   100.000000              13          46
 im1,t=         583   100.000000              14          46
 im1,t=         584   100.000000              15          46
 im1,t=         585   100.000000              16          46
 im1,t=         586   100.000000              17          46
 im1,t=         587   100.000000              18          46
 im1,t=         588   100.000000              19          46
 im1,t=         589   54.0302277              20          46
 im1,t=         590   100.000000               1          47
 im1,t=         591   100.000000               2          47
 im1,t=         592   100.000000               3          47
 im1,t=         593   100.000000               4          47
 im1,t=         594   100.000000               5          47
 im1,t=         595   100.000000               6          47
 im1,t=         596   100.000000               7          47
 im1,t=         597   100.000000               8          47
 im1,t=         598   100.000000               9          47
 im1,t=         599   100.000000              10          47
 im1,t=         600   100.000000              11          47
 im1,t=         601   100.000000              12          47
 im1,t=         602   100.000000              13          47
 im1,t=         603   100.000000              14          47
 im1,t=         604   100.000000              15          47
 im1,t=         605   100.000000              16          47
 im1,t=         606   100.000000              17          47
 im1,t=         607   100.000000              18          47
 im1,t=         608   100.000000              19          47
 im1,t=         609   54.0302277              20          47
 im1,t=         610   100.000000               1          48
 im1,t=         611   100.000000               2          48
 im1,t=         612   100.000000               3          48
 im1,t=         613   100.000000               4          48
 im1,t=         614   100.000000               5          48
 im1,t=         615   100.000000               6          48
 im1,t=         616   100.000000               7          48
 im1,t=         617   100.000000               8          48
 im1,t=         618   100.000000               9          48
 im1,t=         619   100.000000              10          48
 im1,t=         620   100.000000              11          48
 im1,t=         621   100.000000              12          48
 im1,t=         622   100.000000              13          48
 im1,t=         623   100.000000              14          48
 im1,t=         624   100.000000              15          48
 im1,t=         625   100.000000              16          48
 im1,t=         626   100.000000              17          48
 im1,t=         627   100.000000              18          48
 im1,t=         628   100.000000              19          48
 im1,t=         629   54.0302277              20          48
 im1,t=         630   100.000000               1          49
 im1,t=         631   100.000000               2          49
 im1,t=         632   100.000000               3          49
 im1,t=         633   100.000000               4          49
 im1,t=         634   100.000000               5          49
 im1,t=         635   100.000000               6          49
 im1,t=         636   100.000000               7          49
 im1,t=         637   100.000000               8          49
 im1,t=         638   100.000000               9          49
 im1,t=         639   100.000000              10          49
 im1,t=         640   100.000000              11          49
 im1,t=         641   100.000000              12          49
 im1,t=         642   100.000000              13          49
 im1,t=         643   100.000000              14          49
 im1,t=         644   100.000000              15          49
 im1,t=         645   100.000000              16          49
 im1,t=         646   100.000000              17          49
 im1,t=         647   100.000000              18          49
 im1,t=         648   100.000000              19          49
 im1,t=         649   54.0302277              20          49
 im1,t=         650   184.147095               1          50
 im1,t=         651   184.147095               2          50
 im1,t=         652   184.147095               3          50
 im1,t=         653   184.147095               4          50
 im1,t=         654   184.147095               5          50
 im1,t=         655   184.147095               6          50
 im1,t=         656   184.147095               7          50
 im1,t=         657   184.147095               8          50
 im1,t=         658   184.147095               9          50
 im1,t=         659   184.147095              10          50
 im1,t=         660   184.147095              11          50
 im1,t=         661   184.147095              12          50
 im1,t=         662   184.147095              13          50
 im1,t=         663   184.147095              14          50
 im1,t=         664   184.147095              15          50
 im1,t=         665   184.147095              16          50
 im1,t=         666   184.147095              17          50
 im1,t=         667   184.147095              18          50
 im1,t=         668   184.147095              19          50
 im1,t=         669   138.177322              20          50
```

Plus my execution shell is like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

gfortran -fopenmp test.f90 -o test.exe
export export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2
test.exe
```

Comment: Could you explain what the code should do and where to look for what is bad in your output?

Comment: Basically what im trying to do is to collect the array of 'flg' where its coordinate (rlon_mband, rlat_mband) within certain radius (radii) and save it as a new array 'inflg'. As you can notice from the one thread result the order of the index in the new array 'inflg' is monotonically increasing (im=1,2,3...), while if I used multiple threads the order of the array index just changes randomly. I think its something with initializing the 'im1' within each thread. But if you put 'im1' as 'shared' then the order of the index for the new array 'inflg' will be a mess...

Comment: This should be in the question.

Comment: you are right, sorry. I just edited the submitted question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `critical` to serialize part of the loop. It will have negative effect on performance. Also, I don't know if you also need `ordered` or not. `Atomic` might be also possible to use here, with better performance, but I do not see a straightforward way now, maybe someone else.

```
!$omp parallel do default(none) &
!$omp private(m,n,temp)&
!$omp shared(rLonMax,rLonmin,rLatMax,rLatmin)&
!$omp shared(flg,inflg,rlon_mband,rlat_mband,im1)&
do m=1,iScan
 do n=1,iFov
  if ((rLon_Mband(n,m)<=rLonMax) .and.  &
     (rLon_Mband(n,m)>=rLonMin) .and. &
     (rLat_Mband(n,m)<=rLatMax).and.  &
     (rLat_Mband(n,m)>=rLatMin)) then

     temp=sqrt(rLon_Mband(n,m)**2+rLat_mband(n,m)**2)

     if (temp<=radii) then  
        !$omp critical
        inflg(iM1)    = flg(n,m)
        print*,'im1,t=',iM1,flg(n,m), n,m
        iM1 = iM1+1
        !$omp end critical
     end if
  end if
 end do
end do
!$omp end parallel do
```

If the `im1` is `private` it *will* have different value in each thread. Also, this value will be undefined at start by default.

When using `reduction` the reduction variable is undefined inside the loop -> it is not possible to use it here.

Comment: Yes I didn't notice your use of it inside the loop.

Comment: It works okay with small dimension of the arrays as in the test I listed here. Unfortunately my intention is to handle the array with really BIG dimensions. Do you have any other solutions that could improve the performance? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I would prefer to create a separate allocatable private array with `inflg` for each thread and join them together after the loop to the final `inflg`. `im` could then also be private and no synchronization or blocking will be required.

Comment: I think I found a way out: breaking the above task into two loops.  In the first you would compute the "if" statement to get the list of points that are within the radius, i.e.create an logical array such as (inRadius) sharing the same dimension as (ifov, iscan); and then use fortran intrinsic function ‘pack’ to extract the arrays ‘flg’  that has the mark (inRadis==.true.). Thanks so much for the help tho!